# Getting Newest Record from a table using mysql

Tags: mysql, max

This has to be a no brainer, but I am stumped. I'm used to using aggregate 'FIRST' in MsAccess, but MySql has no such thing.
Here is a simple table. I want to return the most recent record based on the date,
for each unique 'group ID'. I need the three records in yellow.

I was asked to add my full query. I tried one of the suggestions using the JOIN feature replacing 't' with the temp table name, but it failed to work. "Can't reopen table 't'" 
 The code is below. I know it's ugly, but it does return the correct data set.

I cleaned up the code a bit and added the JOIN code. Error: "Can't reopen table 't'"

[image: Table]

```
enter code here
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tmpMaxLookupResults`;
```

create temporary table tmpMaxLookupResults
as

```
SELECT 
REPORTS.dtmReportCompleted,
RESULTS.lngMainReport_ID, RESULTS.lngLocationGroupSub_ID
FROM
(tbl_010_040_ProcedureVsTest_Sub as ProcVsSub
INNER JOIN tbl_010_050_CheckLog_RESULTS as RESULTS 
ON (ProcVsSub.lngLocationGroupSub_ID = RESULTS.lngLocationGroupSub_ID)
AND (ProcVsSub.lngProcedure_ID = RESULTS.lngProcedure_ID)
AND (ProcVsSub.lngItemizedTestList_ID = RESULTS.lngItemizedTestList_ID)
AND (ProcVsSub.strPasscodeAdmin = RESULTS.strPasscodeAdmin)
AND (ProcVsSub.strCFICode = RESULTS.strCFICode))
INNER JOIN
tbl_000_010_MAIN_REPORT_INFO as REPORTS ON (RESULTS.lngPCC_ID = 
REPORTS.lngPCC_ID)
AND (RESULTS.lngProcedure_ID = REPORTS.lngProcedure_ID)
AND (RESULTS.lngMainReport_ID = REPORTS.idMainReport_ID)
AND (RESULTS.strPasscodeAdmin = REPORTS.strPasscodeAdmin)
AND (RESULTS.strCFICode = REPORTS.strCFICode)
WHERE
(((RESULTS.lngProcedure_ID) = 143)
AND ((RESULTS.dtmExpireDate) IS NOT NULL)
AND ((RESULTS.strCFICode) = 'ems'))
GROUP BY RESULTS.lngMainReport_ID, RESULTS.lngLocationGroupSub_ID
ORDER BY (REPORTS.dtmReportCompleted) DESC;


SELECT t.* 
FROM tmpMaxLookupResults AS t 
JOIN (
SELECT lngLocationGroupSub_ID, 
MAX(dtmReportCompleted) AS max_date_completed 
FROM tmpMaxLookupResults 
GROUP BY lngLocationGroupSub_ID ) AS dt 
ON dt.lngLocationGroupSub_ID = t.lngLocationGroupSub_ID AND 
dt.max_date_completed = t.dtmReportCompleted
enter code here
```

Comment: Solution: OK, it's real ugly, but for now a temporary solution. I created 2 identical temp tables. then used them with both solutions provided by  Vimal Mahi and Madhur Bhaiya . Both of them worked using 2 temp tables. I know it's not an optimal solution, but will let me get to bed for the night.

Comment: Please see: [How to accept an answer for closure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT 
    tn.*
FROM 
    tableName tn
RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
    (
    SELECT 
        groupId, MAX(date_completed) as max_date_completed
    FROM 
        tableName 
    GROUP BY 
        groupId
    ) AS gt 
    ON 
        (gt.max_date_completed = nt.date_completed AND gt.groupId = nt.groupId)
```

Comment: Turns out my 'tablename' is a temp table and when I run your suggestion I get an error: Can't reopen table 'tn'

Comment: Just saw the edit in your question & understood that you're using temp tables. We cannot refer table more than once in the same query :( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/temporary-table-problems.html
Let me check for alternatives

Comment: No need to research. I created two identical temp tables and was able to get it to work.

Comment: Yeah - Saw your comment in the question yesterday. Glad you slept well :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following SQL.

```
select * from table1 order by date_completed desc Limit 1;
```

Comment: Here was the result:
Date                                   ID            Group
2018-11-05 01:51:00 12040 1675

I want all 3 records

In the image posted, the records I need are all those  highlighted in yellow.

Comment: Your said to your question you need the recent one. If that is the case you need a different sql statement then. What is the logic behind those yellow record?

Comment: Each record highlighted in yellow is the most current date for the particular  record based on the group ID. I guess as I look at the data a bit more, I may have confused it a bit.

Comment: So the most recent report ID for group 1675 is Report 12040, for Group 1674 it's 11971 and for Group 1673, it's report 11958

Answer (score 0):

Use [Order By](https://www.guru99.com/order-by-desc-and-asc.html)

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
ORDER BY your_date_column_name
DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

- In a [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html), get the maximum `date_completed` value for every `group_id`.
- Join this result-set back to the main table, in order to get the complete row corresponding to maximum `date_completed` value for every `group_id`

Try the following query:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM your_table_name AS t 
JOIN (
      SELECT group_id, 
             MAX(date_completed) AS max_date_completed 
      FROM your_table_name 
      GROUP BY group_id 
     ) AS dt 
  ON dt.group_id = t.group_id AND 
     dt.max_date_completed = t.date_completed
```

Comment: Working on it. My DataTable is a temp table in a query, so it's acting up a bit.

Comment: @John please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53182799/edit) the question to add the temp table query as well, and some basic context about what the original query is doing. Maybe there are better workarounds.

Comment: I see where your suggestion would work, just surprised it didn't work with the temp table. I recall I have done something similar before and used temp tables without any issues.